# Python 2.x multiple version issues regarding PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.x, pythonpath

There's Python 2.6 installed in the system.

Now I want to use modules introduced in Python 2.7. Because I have no root privilege, I have built & installed 2.7 under my home directory ($HOME/local/)

I added the following to my $HOME/.bashrc:

```
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/local/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH
```

Now I encountered the two problems I want ask for workarounds.

### 1. Invoking Python 2.7

Newly installed Python 2.7 doesn't find 2.6 modules in system's library path (/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/).

Should I add it to PYTHONPATH manually? Is there any nicer solution?

### 2. Invoking Python 2.6

Python 2.6 complains at startup:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
```

I guess it's trying to load 2.7 modules (in $HOME/local/lib/python2.7).
Is it possible to load only 2.6 modules when Python 2.6 is invoked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1) Invoking python 2.7

In short: don't do this.
There are reasons why the path is called '/usr/lib/python**2.6**/site-packages/'.

One reason is, that in this directory typically the 'compiled' python files (.pyc) are stored. python 2.6 and python 2.7 .pyc files are not compatible:

```
$ python2.7 /usr/lib/python2.6/sitecustomize.pyc
RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file
```

python will skip pyc files which it cannot understood, but you loose at least the benefits of precompiled files.

Another reason is, that things might get mixed up:

```
$ strace -f python2.7 /usr/lib/python2.6/sitecustomize.py
...
stat("/etc/python2.6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/python2.6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/python2.6/apport_python_hook", 0x7fffa15601f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/python2.6/apport_python_hook.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/python2.6/apport_python_hookmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/python2.6/apport_python_hook.py", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/python2.6/apport_python_hook.pyc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python2.7/apport_python_hook", 0x7fffa15601f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/apport_python_hook.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/apport_python_hookmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/apport_python_hook.py", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/apport_python_hook.pyc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2/apport_python_hook", 0x7fffa15601f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
```

I would in your case install the modules needed also for python 2.7 in the python2.7 directory.

### 2) Invoking python 2.6

You might want to have a look at the part of the man page where PYTHONHOME is described:

> PYTHONHOME: Change the  location  of  the  standard  Python  libraries.   By default, the libraries are searched in ${prefix}/lib/python[version] and  ${exec_prefix}/lib/python[version],  where  ${prefix} and  ${exec_prefix} are installation-dependent directories, both defaulting to /usr/local

You can store the python 2.7 specific files / modules in the appropriate directory in your local installation.  Those files / modules will only be picked up when you run the specific version of python. In this case you must not set the PYTHONPATH (or PYTHONHOME).

Note: this is exactly the way Debian (and maybe other distributions) manage different simultaneously installed versions of python.

[Edit: Added section 1 after receiving a comment from niboshi.]

Comment: I think Problem 2 should be fixed with this, but Problem 1 not. Thank you anyway for telling me of PYTHONHOME.

Answer (score 2):

On startup Python takes `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and puts it into `sys.path` variable. 
When you try to import a module it looks to the paths in `sys.path`

Because of:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/local/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH
```

your Python 2.7 paths are in the beginning of `sys.path`, before the paths of Python 2.6 (You can `print sys.path` to check). That means that modules from `$HOME/local/lib/python2.7` will have a priority.

To customize the paths for some of your scripts, either set `PYTHONPATH` per script, or modify `sys.path` (`sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/local/lib/python2.7')` right in your script before any import is done.

Or copy a specific module to your project under a different name. For example i copied `collections` module from Python 2.7 to my project with as `collections27.py`, and in places where i need `OrderedDict` i do `from collection27 import OrderedDict`

> Is it possible to load only 2.6 modules when Python 2.6 is invoked?

Yes, i guess. Just assure that only Python 2.6 modules are in the path - don't use:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/local/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: 1. You can copy for example collections.py (and other modules you need to your project folder. Your project dir is searched for modules in the first place, so when you do `import collections` the one from your project folder will be imported. 2. Tweak PYTHONPATH. If you want libs from Python 2.6 to have priority - put their paths first. Note: check what paths are in effect printing sys.path in your script.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) as an easier alternative.

Once you have pythonbrew installed:

```
$ pythonbrew install 2.7.2
$ pythonbrew switch 2.7.2
```

Comment: Seems nice. But as network is not available in my system, I cannot use it.