# Error after installing EB CLI 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install the elastic beanstalk CLI on an EC2 instance (running AMI) using these instructions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-started.html

I have python 2.7.9 installed, pip and eb.  However, when I try to run eb I get the error below.  It looks like it is still using python 2.6.  How do you fix that?

Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/eb", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('awsebcli==3.0.10', 'console_scripts', 'eb')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 473, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2568, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2259, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..controllers.initialize import InitController
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..core.abstractcontroller import AbstractBaseController
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ..core import io, fileoperations, operations
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ebcli/core/operations.py", line 762
    vars = {n['OptionName']: n['Value'] for n in settings
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Fix your PYTHONPATH to include 2.7 before 2.6. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552898/python-2-x-multiple-version-issues-regarding-pythonpath

Comment: run `which python`, what do you get?

Comment: output of `python --version`?

Comment: python --version gives 2.7.9

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Comment: I also have the same issue. Latest python version, latest pip.

Answer (score 1):

Pip is probably set up with Python 2.6 instead of python 2.7.

```
pip --version
```

You can reinstall pip with Python 2.7, then reinstall 2.6

```
pip uninstall awsebcli
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
pip install awsebcli
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the fix for me was actually to upgrade to latest Beanstalk stack ( `eb upgrade` ). **Note there are downtime** etc. So investigate if you can run the latest stack before upgrading.

Answer (score -1):

The "smartest" solution for me was to install python-dev tools

sudo apt install python-dev

found here:

http://ericbenson.azurewebsites.net/deployment-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-ubuntu/